# Getting Authentication Negotiate instead of NTLM while consuming SOAP WCF Service in Net.Core 2.1

Tags: .net, ntlm, wcf, soap, content-negotiation

I was trying to connect to a WCF SOAP service using NTLM Authentication Scheme, I succeeded at it when using .Net Framework 4.x but when I try to consume the same service in .NET Core 2.1 it fails (because the Authentication scheme is sent as Negotiate despite I set Ntlm in the code), I was using fiddler and I'm attaching some pictures of it.

[image: Net Framework 4.x's Header]
Net Framework 4.x's Header

[image: Net Core 2.1's Headers]

Net Core 2.1's Headers

And this is the source code I'm using .NetCore2.1 and .NetFramework 4.5.x (in which works fine):

```
System.ServiceModel.Channels.CustomBinding binding = new System.ServiceModel.Channels.CustomBinding();
System.ServiceModel.Channels.TextMessageEncodingBindingElement textBindingElement = new System.ServiceModel.Channels.TextMessageEncodingBindingElement();
binding.Elements.Add(textBindingElement);
System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpsTransportBindingElement httpsBindingElement = new System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpsTransportBindingElement();
httpsBindingElement.AllowCookies = true;
httpsBindingElement.MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue;
httpsBindingElement.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
httpsBindingElement.AuthenticationScheme = System.Net.AuthenticationSchemes.Ntlm;
binding.Elements.Add(httpsBindingElement);
return binding;
```

---

```
_client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Domain = "domain";
_client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = "username";
_client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = "password";
_client.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;
```

The error I'm getting in .NetCore2.1 is:

> One or more errors occurred. (The HTTP request is unauthorized with
>   client authentication scheme 'Ntlm'. The authentication header
>   received from the server was 'NTLM, Negotiate'.)

Any help would be really appreciated, thank you!.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution for this? I am having a very similar problem

Comment: Today i had the same issue when trying to connect to an existing wcf service from a console application written in .net core 5. The only solution we could find for now was to remove the negotiate provider in IIS for the wcf service. But tbh i would rather have seen a client only fix for this.